# How can I edit a flash website?

Tags: flash, editing

With firebug, you can easily edit html websites and modify values and whatever you want, but how can I do the same with Flash?

Thank you.

Comment: What’s with all the down-votes‽ Just because you guys happen to know that it’s not possible doesn’t make it a dumb question. It only seems like a silly question with an obvious answer to you because you already know the answer, but frankie3 doesn’t know, which is *why he’s asking*. It’s actually a perfectly valid question and I’m sure a *lot* of novices would wonder it. Sheesh. ◔_◔

Comment: @synetech I agree, I often upvote these questions for exactly this reason, I have done it here too. If there were no people wishing to know more, these sites would not exist.

Comment: The irony is that the due to the new up-votes, the down-votes are now invisible to anyone without at least 250 rep. They’re still there, but just aren’t shown, so my comment now seems strange and hallucinatory. ⊙_ʘ

Comment: @Ramhound, first of all, you expect too much. What do you think this site is for? It *is* research. Second, they *did* learn some stuff, like how to use Firebug to edit the markup of web pages. Finally, how exactly would *you* have researched this, especially if you didn’t know too much about computers?

Comment: @Synetech - I was simply providing feedback to explain my down vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

HTML is just a markup language and as such can be easily read and modified. Flash movies on the other hand are binary files compiled from source code, much like an executable program. Editing those is far more difficult and less intuitive than changing a few lines in an HTML file (unless you have access to the source code, which you probably don't).